# Is Liouville’s condition a special case of the following condition specified by Fourier in his proof that e is irrational?

Tags: number-theory

Is Liouville’s condition a special case of the following condition specified by Fourier in his proof that e is irrational? I ask because consider the following from Liouville

$$0<\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{q^n}$$

A real number x is a Liouville number if and only if there exists infinitely many natural numbers  p, q where $q>0$ such that $$0<\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{q^n}$$ for any n.

Suppose x is a rational number $\frac{c}{d}$ where c and d are of the set of natural numbers and are relatively prime. Then there exists infinitely many natural numbers  p, q where $q>0$ such that $$0<\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{q^n}$$ for any n.
Multiply both sides by $q^n$ to get

$$0<\left|q^nx-pq^{n-1}\right|<1$$

So, $$q^nx-pq^{n-1}$$ is a natural number.

However, notice, there is no natural number that is less than one. So, in order for x to satisfy this condition, it has to be irrational.

For Fourier, a real number x is irrational if and only if there exists infinitely many natural numbers  p, q where $q>0$ such that $$0<\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{q!}$$. Multiply both sides of the inequality by $q!$

$$0<\left|q!x-p(q-1)!\right|<1$$

Comment: It is not at all clear in your question what the "following condition specified by Fourier" is.  Is the condition: "There are are infinitely many integers $p$, $q$ such that $q>0$ and $0<|x-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{q!}$"?

Comment: @halrankard, doesn't  the last condition look like the inequality that Fourier used to prove that e is irrational?

Comment: Yes perhaps. But $$0<|q!x-p(q-1)!|<1$$ is not a well-defined condition or property on the number $x$. In order to obtain a condition *of the number $x$* you need some quantifiers/constraints on the parameters $p$ and $q$. One possibility is the statement I put in my last comment.

Comment: @hanrankard, may I use your parameters?

Comment: Certainly, if that is indeed the condition you have in mind. You also need to change "rational" to "irrational" in the last sentence.

Comment: By the way, you appear to be sketching the proof that Liouville numbers are irrational. But Liouville's condition says: "For any $n$ there are infinitely many pairs $p,q$ of integers, with $q>0$, such that $0<|x-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{q^n}$." You've argued that if $x$ is rational then for any $n$ there are integers $p$ and $q$ (with $q>0$) such that the inequalities $0<|x-\frac{p}{q}|< \frac{1}{q^n}$ fail. This is not the negation of Liouville's condition. This again demonstrates the importance of *fully stating* the conditions you are working with, will all necessary quantifiers etc....

Comment: So does it look like Fourier's condition?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Needs to be re-done in an organized way.

Comment: Three things: (1) Your edits to the part where $x$ is rational have not fixed the issues, and in fact only created more problems.  (2) I cannot answer the question in your last comment because you have not specified what "it" is or what "Fourier's condition" is. (3) I won't make any more comments until you edit your question to include *complete and clear* definitions of these conditions.

Comment: May you please tell me how to make it clear?

Comment: This is what we need to see: "**Definition:** A real number $x$ satisfies **Fourier's condition** if [blah blah blah]." Then in [blah blah blah] you put a clear and complete definition of your condition which includes quantifiers on any other parameters like $p$ and $q$ that are used.

Comment: Sorry. Please forgive me. I am an amateur.